# Pass a parameter from 1 function to another function for loop?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I am not sure this is doable?

But i have 2 functions

```
do_get_array() {
        getArray "/root/1.txt"
        for e in "${array[@]}"
        do
                do_otherfunction $e
        done

}

do_otherfunction() {
        cmd="Print Me $e"
}



getArray() {
    i=0
    while read line # Read a line
    do
        array[i]=$line
        i=$(($i + 1))
    done < $1
}

echo "cmd"
```

SO, passing the parameter from 1 function to the other works.. but i am not sure how to loop until it the last $e in the array? Not sure i explained it correct. It Echo's out the 1st $e but the rest dont. it just stops.

Comment: There are **three** functions. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It Echo's out the 1st $e but the rest dont. it just stops.

You probably meant to do the `echo` inside the function?

```
do_otherfunction() {
    cmd="Print Me $e"
    echo "$cmd"  ## Or simply echo "Print Me $e"
}
```

Or perrhaps you want to save all messages to the variable:

```
do_otherfunction() {
    cmd=${cmd}"Print Me $e"$'\n'
}
```

It would be inefficient though.

Just some suggestions:

```
function do_get_array {
    get_array "/root/1.txt"
    for e in "${array[@]}"; do
        do_other_functions "$e"
    done
}

function do_other_functions {
    echo "Print Me $e"
}

function get_array {
    if [[ BASH_VERSINFO -ge 4 ]]; then
        readarray -t array
    else
        local line i=0
        while IFS= read -r line; do
            array[i++]=$line
        done
    fi < "$1"
}
```

Comment: What would be a better way. I basically have a couple of commands at the bottom of my bash script that ones the function is done it continues at the end of the script.

Comment: What function do you refer to? And what exactly do you want to achieve? Perhaps add more codes or details to your question?

Comment: At the end of the bash script (not a function) there are a set of commands, echo, etc.. I guess it WOULD be smart to make it a function. But how would i loop the function for every string in the array?

Comment: Aren't you doing that with `do_other_functions` already? Or perhaps you want to alter the contents of the array? You can do it by accessing indices instead with `for i "${!array[@]}"; do do_other_functions "$i"; done` then in your functions access `array[$1]`. I'm sorry if I can't follow what you mean much. Perhaps giving more examples and adding comments to what you want to do would help.

Comment: Perfect, i made a function to do the end result and its working just fine. thank you guys!